# ooVoo iOS Sdk, video chat audio is not working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sdk, oovoo

Im using ooVoo sdk, everything is working fine the video, mic but the sound of call is not working on speakers. there is no sound produced during call but my voice is received at other end. I also go through the documentation but in vain.
Any help will be appreciated

```
self.sdk.AVChat.AudioController.initAudio({ (result:SdkResult!) -> Void in
            if result.Result == sdk_error.OK{
                self.sdk.AVChat.AudioController.setConfig(OOVOOAudioModeVoiceChat, forKey: ooVooAudioControllerConfigKey.AudioSetMode)
                self.sdk.AVChat.AudioController.setPlaybackMute(false)
                self.sdk.AVChat.AudioController.setRecordMuted(false)
            }
        })
```

Comment: Mughees i am also using oovoo  sdk but don't know how can i notify other user when i call like there is no feature of ringing

Comment: @guru im using ooVoo for video conference and the sdk has delegate method of didParticipantJoin and i have done everything that i want to there. however you have to play the ringtone on your own by using AVFoundation in respective delegate.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion , i am trying to notify user via push notification when app is not  running, like as whatsApp because i am developing a video calling App .